Finding the basis gates of a Fake HW FakeSherbrooke
I am trying to find the basis gate on FakeSherbrooke. Not sure how to find it?
Below is the sample code related to FakeSherbrooke.
from qiskit_ibm_runtime.fake_provider import FakeBrisbane, FakeSherbrooke
from qiskit_aer.noise import NoiseModel
import math

backend = FakeSherbrooke()
noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend)
coupling_map = backend.coupling_map


Its answer should be basis_gates = backend.operation_names. Sorry for asking such an easy question.

If that is the correct answer, you should post it in the answers and you can also accept your own answer in 24 hours. So people searching for the same question can come across this and get help from you.

Thank you @FDGod

For finding the basis_gates related to a particular Fake Hardware in qiskit== 1.0 , you can use the below line of code:
basis_gates = backend.operation_names
